# update field values by some number using updateAll method in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am a beginner in Yii framework.  I have got a situation where i need to do like this

I have a column `rgt` in database  and i want to increment that by 2 in some conditions.

I have written like these

`Category::model()->updateAll( array("rgt"=>"rgt+2"),array("condition"=>"rgt >".$this->myRight));`

this is not working. I am not sure what i wrote is right. Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: "this is not working" is a very vague statement.  It does not tell us anything about the problem you are having.  It could very well be that rgt isn't even a column in your table.  You need to tell us what you expect, and what is happening.  What error conditions are you getting? What have you tried to resolve this?  What was the result of those attempts (specifically)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass DB expressions like `rgt+2` to `updateAll()`. It will try to set this as column value and probably fail, as the column is of type `INT`. But you could use [`updateCounters()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateCounters-detail) instead:

```
Category::model()->updateCounters(array(
    'rgt' => 2,
), 'rgt > '.$this->myRight);
```